# Changing Log4j file name dynamically

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am implementing Log4j in my project. I would like to log every n (say 10) log entries into new file. I tried using 'RollingFileAppender' but i think it will change log files only based on size and time.

So far i did below code:

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.ControlTable=debug, controlTable
log4j.additivity.ControlTable = false
log4j.appender.controlTable=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controlTable.File=${log4jfilename}
log4j.appender.controlTable.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.controlTable.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.controlTable.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

**Main**

```
public class ControlTableLoggerConsumer {
static {
    System.setProperty("log4jfilename","d:\\control_log_1_9.json");
}
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ControlTable");
private static long logEntries = 0;
public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println("Curr log file:"+logEntries+"::"+System.getProperty("log4jfilename"));
      log.info("Log entry:"+logEntries);
      logEntries++;
      if((logEntries >= 10) && ((logEntries % 10) == 0)) {
         System.out.println("going to change file name to "+"d:\\control_log_"+logEntries+"_"+(logEntries+9)+".json");
         System.setProperty("log4jfilename","d:\\control_log_"+logEntries+"_"+(logEntries+9)+".json");
      }
      if(logEntries == 1000)
         break;
}
```

on console i can see the file name changing for every 10 entries, but in my D drive i can see only one file with all log info.

Comment: Can you remove the log4j2 tag? This is a log4j1-only question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved this issue as below.

```
Properties props = new Properties(); 
    try { 
        InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties"); 
        props.load(configStream); 
        configStream.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("Errornot laod configuration file "); 
    } 
    props.setProperty("log4j.appender.controlTable.File", logFile); 
    LogManager.resetConfiguration(); 
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

Now i can log into to different files dynamically. Hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not seem to be a very good solution to me because:

1. Appender is no longer transparent to your logging code
2. It become extremely messy if you are going to log in different places, for which you need to find a common place to store that `logEntries`.

Consider writing your custom Appender (I bet you can mostly copy what's inside `RollingFileAppender` but just change the triggering criteria from file size to number of records written.

Have had a brief look in the `RollingFileAppender`.  Seems that you can extend from it, and overwrite the `subAppend()` method.

```
public class RowCountRollingFileAppender extends FileAppender {
    // constructors
    // getter setters
    private maxEntries = 10;      // provided through config

    private currentEntries = 0;

    public void rollOver() {
        currentEntries = 0;
        super.rollOver();
    }
    protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
         super.subAppend(event);
         currentEntries++;
         if (fileName != null 
                 && qw != null 
                 && currentEntries > maxEntries) {
             rollOver();
         }
    }
}
```

Then you can have an appender that will roll over if either file hit max size, or it have `n` messages logged.